# Run single xctest from command line

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xctest, xcrun

I have a bunch of xctest in objective-c that work fine when running from XCode6.4
But what I am trying to get is running them one by one from the command line(Terminal) for continuous integration proposes.

I read in some other questions that the tool to use is the xctest. like this:

> xcrun xctest -XCTest TestClass/testMethod
>   TestBundle.xctest

but this doesn't work for me, it says that the TestBundle.xctest is damaged and it can't be loaded because it can't find the UIKit.framework/UIKit.
Some people say that I need to set DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH & DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH. 
Can anyone explain me how I can set this variables and where. and then what I have to do to run them from command line.??

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use facebook's xctool https://github.com/facebook/xctool#usage

It has the option `-only` that you should read about.